# Bash: How to use custom functions (that return true or false) in conditional constructs?

Tags: bash

how do I correctly use custom methods that test an argument, for example, if a string is a word, or a version-number, in a conditional context in `if`, `while`, or `until` statements?

Especially (double) braces seem to have a problem with methods on one side of a test like `-gt`.

Can I just call a method? If yes, what are the context-requirements to do so? So inside/outside of (double) brackets and in the different statements `if`, `while` and `until` - how do they react to calling functions without command substitution?

And if I don't use command substitution to call different test-methods, can I still connect them by boolean operators?

For their connection, are there use-cases where I have to use parentheses or double parentheses?

When do I need command expansion? Could I sometimes need arithmetic expansion for calling functions?

Answer (score 5):

You'd want your function to return success/failure true/false via the exit status like all other commands including the `[` command, by either using the `return` builtin with 0 as argument for true/success and anything else for false/failure or just return with the exit of the last command that is run by the function:

```
isnewer() {
  [ "$1" -nt "$2" ]
  # here returns with the status of the [ command
}

isvowel() {
  case $1 in
    ([aeiouAEIOU]) true;; # or return 0
    (*) false;;           # or return 1
  esac
}
```

That one returns with the exit status of the `case` compound command which itself returns with the last command executed within (so either that of the `true` or the `false` command here).

And then in your `if` / `while` statement, you call those functions, not the `[` command:

```
if isnewer /etc/passwd /etc/shadow; then
  echo passwd newer than shadow
fi
```

```
if isvowel "$x" || isvowel "$y"; then...
```

As to your (unclear to me) references to double-braces or double-parenthesis, while `[` is just a normal command (another name for the `test` command), the Korn shell and some derivatives including `bash` has:

- a `(( arithmetic expression ))` construct, which evaluates the arithmetic expression (following a syntax similar to that of the C language and varying between shells) and returns true/success (via the 0 exit status as usual) if the resulting number is anything but 0. That arithmetic expression syntax does have some comparison and boolean operators similar to those of C (`<`, `>=`, `||`, `&&`...).
- a `[[ conditional expression ]]` construct, which evaluates the conditional expression (with its own syntax, also varying from shell to shell, and reminiscent of the way the `[` parses its argument. That construct, like the `[`/`test` command can be used to perform a number of tests like the `-nt` above or comparing strings or even numbers.

There is however no double-brace operator in bash.